# react datepicker custom css styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-datepicker

i have 2 react datepicker in the project

Have the custom styling like below in the css file

```
.react-datepicker-wrapper,
.react-datepicker__input-container,
.react-datepicker__input-container input {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 13px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

right now it is applying for both datepickers...
but I need the above styling only for 1 datepicker, it shouldn't effect the other datepicker

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it with a custom class name, otherwise it will affect the original class of react-datepicker .

Try this:

```
.myCustomDate-1 {
  .react-datepicker-wrapper,
  .react-datepicker__input-container,
  .react-datepicker__input-container input {
      display: block;
      width: 250px;
      margin-right: 13px;
      margin-left: 3px;
  }
}
```

( P.S. Don't forget that your date picker element needs to add class name "myCustomData-1" . )